# unescaped newline inside substitute pattern

Tags: sed

I have a txt file with a list of 100 countries, without quotation marks around them. I am trying to change this

```
Canada
USA
```

into this

```
countries['Canada']=true
```

etc.

This is the sed command I am trying, with '\1' representing the country in quotation marks.

```
sed -e "s/\(.*\)/countries['\1']=true" source.txt > output.txt
```

The error I'm getting is

> unescaped newline inside substitute pattern

What sed command do I need to achieve what I'm trying to do, and why am I getting this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just missed a trailing `/` at the end:

```
                                       v
$ sed -e "s/\(.*\)/countries['\1']=true/" file
countries['Canada']=true
countries['USA']=true
```

Note also that you don't need to catch group, just match everything with `.*` and then use `&` to print it back:

```
            |-------------|
            vv            v
$ sed -e "s/.*/countries['&']=true/" a 
countries['Canada']=true
countries['USA']=true
```

Comment: thank you. Do you know why it won't work if I try to surround `&` with double quotes instead of single like this `countries["&"]`

Comment: don't worry, got it, need to escape the double quotes.

Comment: @Leahcim probably because you are already using `"` quotes for the `sed` statement. Try to use `sed '...'` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I would just add stuff at the beginning and end:

```
sed -e "s/^/countries['/" -e "s/$/']=true/" source.txt > output.txt
```