# BSD sed; error "unescaped newline inside substitute pattern" when run from script

Tags: shell, sed, sh, freebsd

I am attempting to use (BSD) `sed` to modify my `/etc/gettytab`.  The goal is to modify this entry:

```
P|Pc|Pc console:\
        :ht:np:sp#9600:
```

to this entry:

```
P|Pc|Pc console:\
        :ht:np:sp#115200:\
        :cl=\E[H\E[2J:
```

If I issue the command below (it's on two lines), it works perfectly.

```
# sed -in ' /P|Pc|Pc console/,/^#/ s/9600:/115200:\\\\  
        :cl=\E[H\E[2J:/' /etc/gettytab
```

However, if I use the exact same command (literally copy/paste it) in a script, I get an error message:

```
sed: 1: " /P|Pc|Pc console/,/^#/ ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
```

Searching, I found this post: [unescaped newline inside substitute pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549829/unescaped-newline-inside-substitute-pattern) which talks about the trailing `/`, but I have that in my pattern.

If anyone can assist with what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your script, you escape newlines with a `\`, and you escape the `\` that you're embedding into your output so that it will be interpreted literally. If my math is right, that comes to THREE, not four backslashes.

```
$ cat i
P|Pc|Pc console:\
        :ht:np:sp#9600:
$ cat i.sh
#!/bin/sh

#                                  ┏━━━ escapes the next character,
#                                  ┃┏━━ literal backslash for output,
#                                  ┃┃┏━ escapes the newline.
sed -ne '/^P|/,/^#/ s/9600:/115200:\\\
        :cl=\E[H\E[2J:/' -e p i

$ ./i.sh
P|Pc|Pc console:\
        :ht:np:sp#115200:\
        :cl=E[HE[2J:
$
```

Comment: And I think the only reason your interactive shell was working with four backslashes is that FreeBSD's default shell is tcsh. I'm not going to dive down the csh rabbit hole to figure out why, though. ;-)